# "Yap: revival of the MiKTeX 2.4 render method"

Tags: miktex, viewers

I see on the MiKTeX page, that "Yap: revival of the MiKTeX 2.4 render method" is planned. What does this mean?

Comment: Why don't you ask Christian Schenk himself?

Comment: well, I could have but I do not use yap anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to recall that in MiKTeX 2.4, YAP was a "pure" DVI renderer. After then, presumably because users reported "bugs" when features involving postscript specials were not displayed (since they only appear after the conversion to PS), YAP switched to first running dvips on the file to display and then showing the PostScript output.

This method was slower and perhaps didn't work as well with forward/inverse search between the source and output, but I don't know why MiKTeX would be reverting to the old method now.